# How to work with hex() in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, int, hex

I've problem with hex() in python 2.7
I want to convert '0777' to hex with user input.
but it have problem with using integer with user input.

```
In [1]: hex(0777)
Out[1]: '0x1ff'

In [2]: hex(777)
Out[2]: '0x309'

In [3]: z = raw_input('enter:')
enter:0777

In [4]: z
Out[4]: '0777'

In [5]: hex(z)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3682d79209b9> in <module>()
----> 1 hex(z)


TypeError: hex() argument can't be converted to hex

In [6]: hex(int(z))
Out[6]: '0x309'

In [7]:
```

I need 0x1ff but its showing me 0x309, how i can fix it ?

Comment: So you want octal to hex? What if a user enters `777`?

Comment: so you specifically only want octal input?  `int('8',8) -> error`

Comment: You have to exactly indicate octal digit `hex(0o777)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *base* argument of the [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) class defaults to 10

```
int(x, base=10) -> integer
```

leading zeroes will be stripped. See this example:

```
In [1]: int('0777')
Out[1]: 777
```

Specify base 8 explicitly, then the [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) function will give you the desired result:

```
In [2]: hex(int('0777', 8))
Out[2]: '0x1ff'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input()` instead of raw_input() to eval input and read octal values.

```
In [3]: z = input('enter:')
enter:0777

In [4]: z
Out[4]: 511

In [5]: hex(z)'
Out[5]: '0x1ff'
```

Comment: Don't use`input` ever

Comment: if his input is trust-able, why not?

Comment: how do you make user input *trust-able*?